# sharepoint localization

Tags: custom-masterpage, localization

I have a SharePoint site with variation En,Ar. I want to add new sub-site say Fr but the site in English language but the master-page, menu, titles and the content will be in french and the admin site in English. I create resource file for Ar, en and Fr and it works fine in En and Ar but in Fr still get value En, I update the regional settings and change the language to French but also still get English value form resource file.

Could you help me or any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Solution : 
create httpmodule to switch the languages

public class SwitchLanguageModule : IHttpModule
   {
     private void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object source,EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;

```
        if (application != null)
        {
            HttpContext context = application.Context;
           SPUtility.SetThreadCulture("fr-FR", "fr-FR");    
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have proper language pack installed. Also, check and create a site with correct web language. [Refer here for more](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-new-subsite-in-a-different-language-28361bf2-1bb6-4c73-9ee8-4cb966031cf3)